# Unable to view google bucket images

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have few images on my google cloud bucket.
Once i am trying to view the image the image is downloading. I wants to view it on browser

see the below example.
https://storage.googleapis.com/media-bucket-smartshop/user_tried_images/1000792.png

I need something like this
https://storage.googleapis.com/media-bucket-smartshop/smartshop-bucket-usa/products/B084PZWCBZ/1.jpg

I want it to view like second url

The second image which is working i uploaded manually. Second image i deployed through below code .
I think something is wrong with my code

```
    def upload_to_bucket(local_path, bucket_path):
        blob=bucket.blob(bucket_path)
        file=open(local_path,'rb')
        blob.upload_from_file(file)
        os.remove(local_path)
```

Please take a look